# When does the finite union of convex sets have a hole in it?

Tags: convex-analysis, convexity, real-analysis

Let $f_1, \dots, f_j$ be convex functions from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$.  I am trying to develop a test that decides whether or not the set $\{x | f_1(x) \le k_1\} \cup \dots \cup \{x | f_n(x) \le k_n\}$ has a hole in it of any size (the alternative is that the set is homeomorphic to the unit ball, maybe plus a few lower-dimensional "fingers").

Is anything known about this problem?

Editing in some extra information that is specific to my particular use for this algorithm.  In my algorithm, $n$ of the convex sets that I'm unioning together are the coordinate planes (i.e. $\{x | x_j = 0\}$), and there are exactly $n$ additional convex sets that I care about (so $j = 2n$).

Comment: So it is actually a union and not an intersection?

Comment: 1. You're really asking about the union (not intersection :-) of closed convex sets. 2. Are you attempting a practical algorithm? Then you need restrictions on your convex sets. Algorithms must depend on restrictions (while there is none that would work well universally).

Comment: 1. Yes, it's the union, not the intersection of the sets (the intersection would be convex =) ).  2. Yes, I am attempting a floating-point algorithm.  Rather than place restrictions on the sets, I'm hoping to use standard convex optimization techniques as a subroutine (the $\epsilon$-fudginess in these techniques is okay; I'd be fine with an algorithm that reports "the functions come within $\epsilon$ of being hole-less").

Comment: If you have a way test whether intersections of the convex sets are nonempty, you can adapt the solution to this problem: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21911/when-can-a-freely-moving-sphere-escape-from-a-cage-defined-by-a-set-of-impassib

Comment: Man, that is a cool answer you linked to.  I do have a way to test intersections, so that will do perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Let $K=K_1\cup\dots\cup K_n$ and $K_i$ are convex.

Consider the [nerve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerve_of_a_covering) $N$ of your covering $K_i$.
Note that $N$ is homotopically equivalent to $K$.
(To find $N$ you only need an algorithm which decides that given subcollection of $K_i$ has nonempty intersection.)

Calculate the homology groups of $N$ and 
you may get a "no" answer if you are (un)lucky.